# What is the difference between comparable corpus and parallel corpus?

Tags: nlp, corpus

What is the difference between them, and what can they be used for respectively?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question, please reconsider. This is not "too broad". In fact, the question asks for very specific information. This kind of terminology often confuses students new to the area of statistical machine translation in NLP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **comparable corpus** is a pair of corpora in two different languages, which come from the same domain, as defined in the [Statistical Machine Translation Survey Wiki](http://www.statmt.org/survey/Topic/ComparableCorpora).

A **parallel corpus** is a specific type of comparable corpus, where the text is paired with its translation into a second language. There are many machine translation papers that assume this definition. For example, the main paper from the [Europarl Project](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/).